# Unable to load redisgraph

Tags: redis, redisgraph

I tried the ways like adding
`loadmodule /home/s/webapi/redis-module-graph/src/redisgraph.so`
in redis.conf and
`~/$ redis-server --loadmodule /home/s/webapi/redis-module-graph/src/redisgraph.so`
on [redisgraph.io](http://redisgraph.io).

But I get an error:

> *** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR *** Bad directive or wrong number of arguments

Comment: *as mentioned in redisgraph.io

Comment: s@s-VirtualBox:~/Downloads/redis-stable$ src/redis-server --loadmodule /home/s/webapi/redis-module-graph/src/redisgraph.so
8131:C 19 Mar 18:20:50.818 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
8131:C 19 Mar 18:20:50.818 # **Redis version=4.0.8**, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=8131, just started
8131:C 19 Mar 18:20:50.819 # Configuration loaded

Answer (score 1):

You'll be needing Redis v4 or above to use modules.

The reported error message is indicative of a lower version.

Comment: I used wget http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-4.0.8.tar.gz as mentioned on https://redis.io/download

Comment: Perhaps, but that error message comes from a previous version :)